# Databinding with gridview in windows store metro app

Tags: data-binding, microsoft-metro

I am trying to bind grid view in windows store application, for that I am using simple code, but i is not showing text and images,, only that much no of blocks are displaying.

please help me, how to bind data properly.

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        //itemGridView.ItemsSource = myItems;
        List<MyClass> lsst = new List<MyClass>();
        lsst.Add(new MyClass("Assets/chat.png", "Title1", "Subtitle1"));
        lsst.Add(new MyClass("Assets/chat.png", "Title1", "Subtitle1"));
        lsst.Add(new MyClass("Assets/chat.png", "Title1", "Subtitle1"));
        lsst.Add(new MyClass("Assets/chat.png", "Title1", "Subtitle1"));
        lsst.Add(new MyClass("Assets/chat.png", "Title1", "Subtitle1"));
        lsst.Add(new MyClass("Assets/chat.png", "Title1", "Subtitle1"));

        itemGridView.ItemsSource = lsst;
    }

<GridView
        x:Name="itemGridView"
        AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemsGridView"
        AutomationProperties.Name="Items"
        TabIndex="1"
        Grid.RowSpan="2"
        Padding="116,136,116,46"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource itemsViewSource}}"
        SelectionMode="None"
        IsSwipeEnabled="false">
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="250" Height="250">
                    <Border Background="{ThemeResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}">
                        <Image Source="{Binding ImagePath}" Stretch="UniformToFill" AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding Title}"/>
                    </Border>
                    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Background="{ThemeResource ListViewItemOverlayBackgroundThemeBrush}">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Foreground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemOverlayForegroundThemeBrush}" Style="{StaticResource BaseTextBlockStyle}" Height="60" Margin="15,0,15,0" FontWeight="SemiBold"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Subtitle}" Foreground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemOverlaySecondaryForegroundThemeBrush}" Style="{StaticResource BaseTextBlockStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Margin="15,0,15,10" FontSize="12"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    </GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the datacontext ? and use the IPropertyChanged ?

in your MainView function : `this.DataContext = this;`

Also, implement the IPropertyChanged interface. Google it, you will find the solution ;-)